# LWC: Click-jacking due to CSS Vulnerability

Tags: lightning-web-components, security-review

we received an issue in our salesforce security report "LWC: Click-jacking due to CSS Vulnerability". It list out CSS files where this issue is reported but no more info is provided for this.

I tried to find any reason why this issue is reported and how we can fix this issue.

Css files in which this issue is reported

```
.outer-wrapper{
    background-color: #fff;
    position: relative;
}
.gv-gutters{
    margin-right: calc(-1 * var(--lwc-spacingSmall,0.75rem));
    margin-left: calc(-1 * var(--lwc-spacingSmall,0.75rem));
    margin-top: calc(-1 * var(--lwc-spacingSmall,0.75rem));
}
.top-banner{
    background-color: #ecebea;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 6px 0px 6px 12px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px #ccc;
}
.small-heading{
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
}
.title-container{
    line-height: 15px;
}
.breadcrumb-text{
    color: #0070d2;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.fields-container{
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px #ccc;
    padding: 6px 0px 6px 12px;
}
.slds-box{
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px #ccc;
}
.card-title{
    background-color: #ecebea;
}
.large-heading{
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 500;
}
.block-container-disabled{
    position:relative;
}
.block-container-disabled:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    z-index:1;
    background: #f3f3f3;
    opacity: 0.3;
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
.footer-banner{
    background-color: #ecebea;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 6px 0px 6px 20px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
}
.slds-spinner_container{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9002 !important;
}
lightning-button.button {
    --slds-c-button-radius-border: 16px;
}
```

other file

```
.detail-container{
    position: relative;
    min-height: 70vh;
}
.detail-footer{
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Is there any salesforce documentation for this issue and its resolution.
Thanks

Comment: As stated in answer , it's indirectly documented. I found [this](https://auth0.com/blog/preventing-clickjacking-attacks/) link helpful for understanding this vulnerability.

Answer (score 3):

This is [documented](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/secure_code_violation_css_outside_components.htm) as disallowed in the ISVforce guide, and it's all down to absolute positioning which can be used to implement "[clickjacking](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_clickjack_protection_configure.htm&type=5)". By positioning an invisible layer in front of some screen components and intercepting a click you could cause that click to perform an action other than what the user expected (including causing malicious action).

You can potentially use [SLDS modals](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/modals/) to address the need to mask the background and provide an overlay. Note the "slds-backdrop" and "slds-backdrop_open" styling classes.

You should try to adopt [SLDS](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/), using the SLDS style classes, wherever possible since this avoids using constructs like this that are banned.

Comment: +1 for the doc. But it's indirectly stated and Salesforce should have listed all vulnerabilities in a article I feel.

Comment: @Rohit I agree. I know about this having failed a review with it...

Comment: Ohh ,ok. I'am chasing Salesforce Support for some other LWC vulnerability which they haven't documented...

Comment: Like I said, using SLDS for as much of your CSS as possible avoids clickjacking and related "review failure" issues. We have very few CSS files with our LWCs for this reason.

Comment: @PhilW but if our components are not global and we are using them inside our pages or tabs will then also it will be considered a Vulnerability?

Comment: By global, do you mean exposed? Any exposed component can be used in any lightning page or other declared target, in or outside your package. Unless you can persuade Salesforce you *have* to roll your own, and cannot use SLDS, then it doesn't really matter if it really is a vulnerability...